# How to get query s3 bucket by specific file size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

at the moment there's some files being uploaded where they are getting corrupted. They'll have a filesize of 0 bytes. May I ask how do I query my s3 bucket and filter by specific size, i'm trying to query when byte is 0?

[image]

At the moment I have two queries.

First one list all the files recursively in the bucket but no sorting.

```
aws s3 ls s3://testbucketname --recursive --summarize --human-readable
```

Second one sorts but only when provided a prefix, in my case the prefix is the folder name. My current bucket structure is as followed `{accountId}/{filename}`

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --max-items 10 --bucket testbucketname --prefix "30265"  --query "sort_by(Contents,&Size)"
```

30265 is the accountId/folder name. When the prefix isn't provided, the sort doesn't quite work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This query works well for filtering the name which is a string

aws s3api list-objects --bucket testbucketname --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '.jpg')]"

Unfortunately I couldn't use contains for Size and there isn't a equals.

Comment: I would recommend using S3 inventory and query it with Athena.

Comment: You could also potentially use Lambda to alert you in real time to objects being uploaded with zero size (which is inherently an indication that your client sent zero bytes).

Comment: Do you just mean something like ``aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket example-bucket --query 'Contents[?Size==`0`].Key'`` (Use `"` instead of `'` on Windows)?

Comment: @AnonCoward exactly that, TY! Did you want to post an answer

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72172684/how-to-recursively-delete-s3-objects-of-size-0-using-the-aws-cli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`--query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html) logic to filter the list objects locally to only those that are zero-byte big:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket example-bucket --query 'Contents[?Size==`0`]'
```

Or, if you just want to see the list of keys without other meta-data, you can further filter the list:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket example-bucket --query 'Contents[?Size==`0`].Key'
```

(For both of these, replace the outer `'` with `"` when running on Windows.)

Further, if the goal is the remove these objects, you can use jq and a subshell to construct a query that deletes the targeted objects:

```
aws s3api delete-objects --bucket example-bucket --delete \
"$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket example-bucket --query 'Contents[?Size==`0`].Key' |\
 jq '{"Objects": map({"Key":.})}')"
```

There isn't a direct way to do this same sort of construct with Windows's command interpreter.